# Dates and implausible dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe

This problem pertains to a data frame consisting of missing values, dates and some implausible dates having negative signs preceding the day and/or the month. I read the data from an excel file into R using the code

```
df <- data.frame(read_excel("dat.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric", "guess")))
```

This changes the dates to numeric values. Of course, if I want to obtain the dates, I can replace "guess" in the above code with "date". However, I want to obtain the implausible dates and replace all other entries with NA. An example of the data frame is

```
df<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
"date" = c("-2/8/2018","-22/11/2018","-1/-2/2018",39586,"NA"))
```

The numeric value 39586 is actually a date (i.e. 11/04/2008) that was converted to numeric after reading the excel file into R.

With the use of

```
df$date<-df[is.integer(df$date)] <- NA
```

I tried to convert all integers to NA and keep the implausible dates, but all the components of the date column changes to NA, that is

```
  id date
1  1   NA
2  2   NA
3  3   NA
4  4   NA
5  5   NA
```

How can this be resolved? The expected output would look like

```
  id        date
1  1   -2/8/2018
2  2 -22/11/2018
3  3  -1/-2/2018
4  4          NA
5  5          NA
```

Secondly, how can I remove the minus sign attached to the dates? I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Do you really have negative dates coming from Excel?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the negative dates are coming from Excel. The negatives associated with the day and month means these days and months are unknown.

Comment: And does a missing day/month disqualify that date, or would there be some default value(s) you would want to use in place of the unknown values?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks! This is a good question. If we could replace the unknown values with 99 that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the given example ?

Comment: @RonakShah I have shown the expected output.

Comment: you can get your expected output by doing `replace(df$date, !grepl('-?\\d+/-?\\d+/\\d+', df$date), NA)` Or to remove negative sign `replace(gsub("-", "", df$date), !grepl('-?\\d+/-?\\d+/\\d+', df$date), NA)` but would that be useful to you?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks! how can I replace the days and months with the minus sign with 99. For example, -22/11/2018 to be seen as 99/11/2018 and -1/-2/2018 as 99/99/2018.

Comment: `gsub("-\\d{1,2}", "99", df$date)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to replace numbers with negative sign to 99 and then use `replace` to turn values to `NA` which do not follow the date pattern.

```
df$date <- gsub("-\\d+", "99", df$date)
df$date <- replace(df$date, !grepl("\\d+/\\d+/\\d+", df$date), NA)
df

#  id       date
#1  1  99/8/2018
#2  2 99/11/2018
#3  3 99/99/2018
#4  4       <NA>
#5  5       <NA>
```